# Trouble outputting names in a backpack problem

Tags: java, arrays

I was trying to solve a problem based on value and weight. In the task i had to pick out the elements by their value and weight, and find the highest efficiency solution. I receive an answer, however i am having trouble outputting the elements that were used in order to get an answer.

I've tried creating a string in which i place the values, however it gives out an outofbounds error.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String z[] = new String[]{"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","l","m"};
    int w[] = new int[]{10,2,4,6,8,1,7,11,4,5};
    int c[] = new int[]{20,3,5,7,4,1,8,15,8,6};
    int maxW = 50;
    int n = c.length;
    System.out.println("");
    int a = Find(w,c,maxW,n,z);
    System.out.println("max value is " + a);
}

static int max(int a, int b)        
{
    if(a>b)
    {
        return a;
    }
    return b;
} 


public static int Find(int w[],int c[], int maxW,int n, String[]z)
{ 
    int K[][] = new int[n + 1][maxW + 1]; 
    String s = "";
    // Build table K[][] in bottom up manner 
    for (int i = 0; i<= n; i++)
    { 
        for(int j = 0; j<= maxW; j++)
        { 
            if (i == 0 || j == 0)
            {
                K[i][j] = 0;
            }
            else if (w[i - 1]<= j)
            {
                K[i][j] = max(c[i - 1] + K[i - 1][j - w[i - 1]], K[i - 1][j]); 
            }
            else
            {
                K[i][j] = K[i - 1][j];
            }

        } 
    } 
    return K[n][maxW]; 
}
```

}

i want to output the same index element in string z, as the index element that is used to find the efficiancy.
The ideal result would be something like this in a string:
a a a b c d e m
(Just an example)
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The call to `static int max(int a, int b)` can be replaced by just `Math.max(a, b)`.

Comment: `z` is not a string, `z` is an array of strings - you're getting the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because you're trying to access an index in the array that does not exist.

Comment: @MCEmperor Thank you!

Comment: @JonnyHenly Yes, however when i try to add z[i] to the string s, i get the error despite me placing it outside the second forloop. Do you know how to fix it?